# AJAX on success call 2 functions

Tags: javascript, ajax, codeigniter

Hi how can I call 2 functions when AJAX is success? My code is below and I am using Codeigniter. I have 3 select fields in the view and when the first select is changed, it will call the model by the controller and get the materials based on the car chosen. After that, it should also get the colors, which is the third field based on the material chosen.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#car').change(function(){ 
      $("#material > option").remove(); 
      var car_id = $('#car').val(); 
      $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "http://localhost/wheel_configurator/user/get_material/"+car_id,
          success: function(materials)
          {
            $.each(materials,function(materialID,materialName)
            {
              var opt = $('<option />'); 
              opt.val(materialID);
              opt.text(materialName);
             $('#material').append(opt);
            });
         }
     });
   });

    $('#material').change(function(){ 
        $("#color > option").remove();
        var material_id = $('#material').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://localhost/wheel_configurator/user/get_color/"+material_id, 
            success: function(colors) 
            {
                $.each(colors,function(colorID,colorName) 
                {
                    var opt = $('<option />'); 
                    opt.val(colorID);
                    opt.text(colorName);
                    $('#color').append(opt);
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Just call the 2 functions from within success.

Comment: I have updated the question, sorry for being vague @Barry.

Answer (score 0):

First: 
What the problem? You have block

```
$.each(materials,function(materialID,materialName)
{
    ....
}
```

You can do whatever you want there. Call as much functions as you wish.

Second: It's not php question. It's Javascript/jquery question.

Comment: I have updated the question, sorry for being vague @Darth Kotik.